# How to copy data between multiple Jenkins master and slave setup

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I have two jenkins masters, namely A and B. I am wondering how would a slave from master A copy data from master B? Is there any plugin available to do this kind of job?

Answer (score 0):

There are few plugins that can help:

- [Publish via SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)
- [Publish to a FTP server](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+FTP+Plugin)
- [Publish to a Windows file share](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin)

Also you may try [this python script](https://gist.github.com/supertom/2759847) to download last successful artifacts from Jenkins via Rest API. We use it in our production and it works very well.